# Switch Partition using a Select Statement instead of Entire Table

Tags: sql, database-partitioning

I am using partition switching to put a table into a partition as follows.

```
ALTER TABLE sourceTable SWITCH PARTITION partitionNumber TO targetTable PARTITION partitionNumber
```

Can I replace sourceTable with a select query restricted to part of the source table?

Answer (score 1):

Partition switching is useful because it is a metadata-only operation. It will execute quickly regardless of the size of the data. It does not touch data at all.

If you want to apply a filter, data must be touched. The switch operation cannot provide that. It would not give any performance advantages compared to a manual `DELETE` or `INSERT`.